# how to convert byte array to pdf and download

Tags: javascript, blob, filesaver.js

I am trying to do a simple task of downloading a http response to a pdf. I am generating a pdf file but I am getting an error of "Failed to open PDF".

Here is what the response looks like.
[image: screenshot]

And here is what I am doing.

```
 let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
 FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'foo.pdf')
```

Comment: The response there doesn't look like a PDF file (PDF is a text file and should start with `%PDF.`). Have you checked that XMLHttpRequest uses the correct URI?

Comment: I am not sure what it is. I am trying out different ways of displaying it. here is a fiddle i forked and added the response. Maybe this will help figure it out?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8vzz8sk9/

Comment: is it a base64 response? That is what I assumed at first

Comment: Ah Ok, the string base-64 encoded. Simply decode it via f.ex. via fetch/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string from the response seem to be Base-64 encoded (ref. fiddle). You can decode it using `fetch()` (or `XMLHttpRequest()` for older browsers):

```
fetch("data:application/pdf;base64," + response.data)
  .then(function(resp) {return resp.blob()})
  .then(function(blob) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'foo.pdf')
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for solution with same problem, [here](https://medium.com/@riccardopolacci/download-file-in-javascript-from-bytea-6a0c5bb3bbdb) is the nice article with cross browser support.

Snippet from article:

> ```js
> const binaryString = window.atob(fileResponseData);
> const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
> const mappedData = bytes.map((byte, i) => binaryString.charCodeAt(i));
> const blob = new Blob([mappedData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
> FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'foo.pdf')
> ```