# convert byte array to PDF in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I make an call to external service which returns a PDF file. It is received as byte stream in my code. How do we convert the byte array and send it back as my service response?

Comment: Can you please add some code on what you are currently doing?

Answer (score -1):

You can decode it using fetch() (or XMLHttpRequest() for older browsers).
For more information you could checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867354/7735091).